# enforce generic types in maps (in relation to key/value generics)

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I want to have some kind of a cache that did something like

```
Map<Class<T extends SomeBaseClass>, List<T>> cache = new ...
```

When I try to do this is throws compile errors. I don't want to make them generics of the class I'm working with, because they don't belong there. I also will have many different kinds of T there. But I also don't want to use `<? extends SomeBaseClass>` because you don't have a compile time guarantee that the list going in is of the same type the class that maps to it is...

What are my options here? These terms are so overused here and on google I can't seem to search for them :-(

Comment: Why not just use `Map<SomeBaseClass, List<T>>`?

Comment: What are the compilation errors you get?

Comment: Have a look at ClassToInstanceMap in Guava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also will have many different kinds of T there.

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to use generics to somehow guarantee that each entry in the map will associate a Class object with some object of the class in question.

Generics cannot do that.  Let's quote your code snippet:

```
Map<Class<T extends SomeBaseClass>, List<T>> cache = new ...
```

It looks like you want each entry in the `Map` to associate a `Class` object with an instance of that class.  Well, generics can't do anything to help you there, because the type parameter `T` in `Map<Class<T>,T>` will have one and only one type substituted for it when the type is specialized to a particular `T`.  This means a specialized `Map<Class<Foo>,Foo>` version of the class will have a method with this signature:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<Class<Foo>,Foo>> entries();
```

And the `Map.Entry<Class<Foo>,Foo>>` references you get out of the `Set`'s `iterator` method would have these methods:

```
public Class<Foo> getKey();
public Foo getValue();
```

In this case, well, there is only one value for `Class<Foo>`, which is the class object for the `Foo` class.  But if we go with your example and use `Class<T extends SomeBaseClass>` doesn't really add much; `getKey()` will get you some `Class` object whose `newInstance` method produces something that can be cast to `Foo`, but there is no guarantee that `getValue()` will get you a value of the same runtime class, or even of a class that can be cast to the same class as the one returned by `getKey()`.

**EDIT:** You probably want something like this (untested, not even tried to compile it):

```
public class InstanceTable {
    private final Map<Class,Object> table =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Class,Object>();

    public <T> void put(Class<T> klass, T value)
        throws ClassCastException {
        table.put(klass.cast(value));
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> klass) {
        return klass.cast(table.get(klass))
    }

}
```

This offers compile-time type-safety *only* in the case where you statically name the classes you're using in the source code, using the `Foo.class` syntax:

```
InstanceTable t = new InstanceTable();
t.put(String.class, "foo");          // compiles
t.put(Integer.class, "bar")          // doesn't compile
String foo = t.get(String.class);    // compiles
Integer one = new Integer(1);
Integer bar = t.get(one.getClass()); // doesn't compile
```

But understand that beyond this, it isn't using the type system to enforce the invariant you want at compilation time —it's still checking it at runtime (the calls to [`Class.cast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29)).

Answer (score 3):

There are no options.  This isn't avoidable, although you can wrap it up in your own API that hides the type casts...but there's no way to guarantee this sort of thing in Java at compile time.

That said, you can create an API that's typesafe for use on the outside, and suppresses warnings on the inside.  (@ysdx suggested looking at Guava's [ClassToInstanceMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html), which is indeed a good example.)  But you're not going to get something that's *internally* type-safe: there are going to be casts on the inside.

Comment: Can you by chance cite a source with a reason why the decision was made to not allow this?

Comment: Doing this would require a massively more powerful type system.  I'm not sure I know of _any_ languages with a type system strong enough to make these kinds of guarantees, with the possible exception of Agda...and in all honesty, Agda is mostly a research language, not something that people tend to use in the real world.  (Sorry, Agda fans.  As a Haskell fan, I empathize.)

Comment: That said, you can create an API that's typesafe for use on the outside.  (@ysdx suggested looking at Guava's ClassToInstanceMap, which is indeed a good example.)  But you're not going to get something that's _internally_ type-safe: there are going to be casts on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

so you want a map of

```
String.class --> list of strings
Int.class --> List of Integers
```

Ok, no prob. But: in a particular instance of your map:

```
Map<K, V> x = …;
```

What particular, specific class is K? You want it to be a whole buch of different ones at once, which aint going to happen.

You are going to have to do some casting.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this in `TypedMap`: http://blog.pdark.de/2010/05/28/type-safe-object-map/

Here is some demo code:

```
TypedMap map = new TypedMap();

String expected = "Hallo";
map.set( KEY1, expected );
String value = map.get( KEY1 ); // Look Ma, no cast!
assertEquals( expected, value );

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
map.set( KEY2, list );
List<String> valueList = map.get( KEY2 ); // Even with generics
assertEquals( list, valueList );
```

The magic is in the key:

```
final static TypedMapKey<String> KEY1 = new TypedMapKey<String>( "key1" );
final static TypedMapKey<List<String>> KEY2 = new TypedMapKey<List<String>>( "key2" );
```