# Avoiding warnings with generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have snippet of code with generics which is stripped to its core looks something like this. There is trivial generic interface

```
public interface Doubler<T> {
    T doubling (T param);
}
```

and there is factory method that returns different instances of this interface

```
public class DoublerFactory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doubler<String> input = produceDoubler("String");
        System.out.println(input.doubling(args[0]));
    }

    public static <T> Doubler<T> produceDoubler(String type) {
        Doubler result;
        switch (type) {
            case "Integer" : result =  new IntDoubler(); break;
            case "Float" : result = new FloatDoubler(); break;
            case "String" : result = new StringDoubler(); break;
            default: result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }


    static class IntDoubler implements Doubler<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer doubling(Integer param) {
            return param*2;
        }
    }

    static class FloatDoubler implements Doubler<Float> {
        @Override
        public Float doubling(Float param) {
            return param*2;
        }
    }

    static class StringDoubler implements Doubler<String> {
        @Override
        public String doubling(String param) {
            return param + param;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except that last line in factory method "produceDoubler" produces "Unchecked assignment" warning. I actually understand why - what I can't figure out is how to write this snippet so that Java compiler is fully satisfied with assignments.

Comment: Don't operate on `String` values. Use `Class` with Louis' suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088782/enforce-generic-types-in-maps-in-relation-to-key-value-generics).

Answer (score 3):

```
public static <T> Doubler<T> produceDoubler(String type) {
```

What this signature says is that someone can call `produceDoubler` for any type `T` the *caller* wants, *completely* irrespective of `type`, and `produceDoubler` can return the appropriate Doubler.  Of course, it can't.  But that could do something silly like

```
Doubler<Color> doubler = produceDoubler("Integer");
```

which of course makes no sense.  There's no sensical way to double a color, and there's no relationship between the type and the string.

The only way to make the compiler happy would be to return a `Doubler<?>`, but this would of course force you to do unsafe casts when you tried to *use* the `Doubler`.

There *isn't* actually a typesafe way to do this -- to connect arbitrary `String`s to different types.  The only typesafe alternative would be to lift out the `switch` -- to do at the top level something like

```
switch (type) {
   case "Double": {
      Doubler<Double> doubler = new DoubleDoubler();
      // use the doubler for everything you need to use it for
   }
   ...
}
```

...without trying to store a doubler of a non-concrete type at any time.

Answer (score 0):

A possible signature for your factory method would ask for the Class of the desired type:

```
public class DoublerFactory() {
    public <T> Doubler<T> produceDoubler(Class<? extends T> cls) {
        // This accepts both Class objects designating the primitive type and its object
        // wrapper, although obviously the result always uses the Object-derived wrapper
        if (Integer.TYPE.equals(cls) || Integer.class.equals(cls))
            return new IntDoubler();
        if (Float.TYPE.equals(cls) || Float.class.equals(cls))
            return new FloatDoubler();
        if (String.class.equals(cls))
            return new StringDoubler();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

// User code
DoublerFactory df = //...
Doubler<Float>  flt = df.produceDoubler(Float.class);
Doubler<String> str = df.produceDoubler(String.class);
```

This way, you can maintain the compile-time type safety of the code, while still proving a factory interface.

A differnt implementation could use a map of `Class<?>` keys to `Supplier<? extends Doubler<?>>`, allowing you to add/remove mappings at runtime. You would once again have an unchecked cast, but this time it can be safely suppressed:

```
public class DoublerFactory() {
    private Map<Class<?>, Supplier<? extends Doubler<?>> doublerMakers;

    public DoublerFactory() {
        doublerMakers = new HashMap<>();
        addReg(Integer.TYPE, IntDoubler::new);
        addReg(Integer.class, IntDoubler::new);
        addReg(Float.TYPE, FloatDoubler::new);
        addReg(Float.class, FloatDoubler::new);
        addReg(String.class, StringDoubler::new);
    }

    // Using this function instead of directly calling Map.put in the constructor
    // allows the compiler to check that the concordancy in T is respected
    private <T> void addReg(Class<? extends T> cls, Supplier<? extends Doubler<T>> maker) {
        doublerMakers.put(cls, maker);
    }

    public <T> Doubler<T> produceDoubler(Class<? extends T> cls) {
        Supplier<? extends Doubler<?>> maker = doublerMakers.get(cls);
        if (maker == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        // The cast here is unavoidable, but we know that if all mappings are inserted 
        // using the addReg() method, then the result is type safe.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Doubler<T> ret = (Doubler<T>)(Doubler)maker.get();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually didn't compile for me with the following error: Error:(11, 49) java: incompatible types: org.test.DoublerFactory.IntDoubler cannot be converted to org.test.Doubler<T> and so on.

Comment: You're completely right, I focused too much on the point made on the other answer that using a String key was not type safe towards the user code. *Inside* the factory you'll always have some point of unchecked casting, I fear. My first example would require it in the same place as your question (the only advantage over your code is that the compiler forces the user code to use the correct variable type). Sorry for not being clear on this aspect.